# HIgh cpu usage for Compiz process on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiz, cpu

I'm having very annoying issue: the compiz process eats up to 50-60% of the CPU resources on my dedicated server. I'm not really experienced with Ubuntu. I need to help to disable visual effects and somehow optimize compiz to eat less CPU time.

Comment: Please ignore my ignorance - but why would a server have visual effects? Usually you don't run no UI on a server.

Comment: I'm really noob when it's comes to non-Windows OS. I use gui to to do certain stuff, like copying files, adding some settings etc.

Comment: Well - as you prefer - but running a server without UI should save you a lot of resources - so on the longterm it might make sense to get used to the commandline and if needed use something like `mc` for file operations.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to disable visual effects. Open Preferences > Appearance, click on the Visual Effects tab. Select None and you're good to go ;)

Comment: Thank for your reply. I found Appearance, but I can't see anything related to visual effects: http://i.imgur.com/q7DEvdv.png

Comment: What about uninstalling compiz?